# Rails flash.now within after_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Code on this one speaks for itself.

This works...

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Something got borked!'
  end

end
```

And this doesn't (`flash` is empty)...

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  after_action :test_flash

  def index
  end

  def test_flash
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Something got borked!'
  end

end
```

Using Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.1.0

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `index` action rails just renders the `new` page as you have not specified anything different.
`after_action` is executed after rendering the index page i.e., it adds a callback which would be called after the execution of index action is completed. So, `test_flash` has no effect as its too late and index page is already rendered.

EDIT:

If you want to call test_flash before rendering then you can override `render` method and do something like :

```
  def render *args
    test_flash
    super
  end
```

Comment: Okay, so that explains the behavior, thanks, Kirti! Now how can I work around it? Is there something I can do inside `index` in order to get that `action_filter` to behave the way I want?   (Note: moving the `flash.now` call into the action method is not an option in my situation.)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, Kirti! You have helped me solved a problem that has dogged me for a week now. You rock.